# Why template function is giving error in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have template function

```
template<typename A,typename B,typename C>
C fun(A a,B b)
{
    return (string)(a+b);
}
```

And my main is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto c= fun(10,20.3);
    cout<<c;
    return a.exec();
}
```

If I execute this it says
  In function    `int main(int, char**)`

error: no matching function for call to    `fun(int, double)`

Please let me know why I can't do this, or is this wrong?

Comment: How do you think `C` will be deduced from your call to `fun`?

Comment: Remove C, use auto

Comment: Good to know the site lets you see who downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary you will need a [**good C++ book**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list);

---

First, You cannot "simply cast" objects to `std::string` in C++, (conversion in C++ follow some principles that we cannot explain fully here<sup>1</sup>). worse primitive types. For numeric types there is a function [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for that

Secondly, there is such a thing known as [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) which automatically deduces template parameters from arguments used to instantiate a *function template* or *class template*(C++17). In, `C fun(A a, B b)` - where `A, B, and C` are all template types. There is simply no way to deduce `C` with some further sorcery. or you could use a placeholder return type `auto`?

<sup>1</sup>Again, you should get [**good C++ book**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list);

Comment: Thank you! so much

Comment: Don't worry about it, just select a good C++ material from the above link. You will appreciate it. - As for the `auto` *placeholder return type*, it would work for some limited cases in a C++11 compiler, and for broader cases in C++14. Again, if you don't know about these C++11, and C++14 compilers and/how to enable them on a recent version of your compiler, consult the materials and/or compiler docs,